# Add "A"-directive to parent node and execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, draggable, angular-directive

I'm a newbie in Angular.js and I stuck with one problem.

I want to integrate this plugin (https://github.com/pratyushmittal/angular-dragtable) to be able to drag columns in my table.
The whole table is a directive. Each `<th>` also renders by a directive.

```
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="col in table.columns" my-column></th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
   </table>
```

According to plugin documentation I need to set **draggable** directive to table. If I set it manually it doesn't grab my columns properly, because this columns is not rendered at that moment, and this doen't work. In **my-column** directive I'm waiting for last **< th >**

```
.directive('myColumn', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'templates/column.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (scope.$last)
        $timeout(function() {
            //scope.$emit('lgColumnsRendered');
            angular.element(element).closest('table').attr('draggable', 'draggable');
        });
    }
  }
}])
```

And when last th is rendered I going up to my table and set this directive. For sure it is stupid and doesn't work. I also read about `$compile` but I need add attribute-directive to already existing table in my DOM.

Maybe I go wrong way and don't understand concept of doing this, but you catch the idea? How can I do this?

Comment: Did my answer help to solve the problem? If it doesn't - please comment on it, so we can come to the solution. And if it works for you - consider marking the answer as accepted, so others will now that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that angular-dragtable doesn't expect that table columns will be dynamic.
And I think it is logical assumption - in most cases table **rows** will be dynamic (which is OK for the dragtable), but columns are usually static.

The solution to this is to add a special event to the dragtable to ask it for re-initialization when your columns are created, here is the modification I made to dragtable (see the link to the full source below):

```
project.directive('draggable', function($window, $document) {
    function make_draggable(scope, elem) {
        scope.table = elem[0];
        scope.order = [];
        scope.dragRadius2 = 100;

        var headers = [];
        init();

        // this is the event we can use to re-initialize dragtable 
        scope.$on('dragtable.reinit', function() {
            init();
        });

        function init() {
            headers = scope.table.tHead.rows[0].cells;
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                scope.order.push(i);
                headers[i].onmousedown = dragStart;
            }
        }

        function dragStart($event) {
```

Now in your code you can do this:

```
    .directive('myColumn', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', function($timeout, $rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'templates/column.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (scope.$last)
            $rootScope.$broadcast('dragtable.reinit');
        }
      }
```

Here is a [full code](https://github.com/serebrov/so-questions/tree/master/angular-dynamic-directive) of the example I tested the issue on.